# mysql_fetch_assoc into mysqli in a function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I have a function to gather `user_data` in PHP & MYSQL, and the thing is that I want to upgrade `MYSQL` in `MYSQLi`.

The `MYSQL` code is following:

```
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM members where id = $id"));
```

The `MYSQLi` code I tried but with no use:

```
$data = $db_connect->query("SELECT $fields FROM ´members´ where id = $id");
```

and

```
$result = $db_connect->query("SELECT $fields FROM ´members´ where id = $id");
$data = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

I don't know what could be wrong, in the 1:st example I have no errors but the data isn't displaying, and in the 2:nd code I noticed I need the `fetch_assoc` function to make it work, but here I get the errors saying

> Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Comment: How is $fields declared? And what's with the odd quote marks around 'members'?

Comment: $fields = '`' . implode('`, `',$func_get_args) . '`';   between '' there is actually '`'

Comment: Those aren't backticks. Compare \`select\` to ´select´.

Comment: @ethrbunny: Quite right!  I'll get my eyes checked.

Comment: @ethrbunny There are backsticks, but they makrk my answer instead

Comment: +1 for converting to `mysqli_`

Comment: @YourCommonSense so you give (-) because of something I don't know about, well that's nice of you to do that without explaining or giving a link that explain how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have an error in your query. [`MySQli->query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) will return `FALSE` on failure.

[UPDATE 2] Try this code:

```
$result = $db_connect->query("SELECT $fields FROM members where id = $id");

if (!$result) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $db_connect->error);
}
else {
    while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        print_r ($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the following error `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array`, but still have no idea what is wrong, I have `$data = array();` in my function is this wrong?

Comment: Please try the updated code instead. The updated code should throw the correct error message now.

Comment: Now I get that this code you updated is wrong: 
`Fatal error: in C:\WebServer\htdocs\project\includes\functions.php on line 118`

Comment: Now I get this: `Errormessage: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '�members´ where id = '1'' at line 1`

Comment: That is the error message I was looking for. It means that your query has a syntax error. Try the original query instead:
    `SELECT $fields FROM members where id = $id`

Comment: Finally! After a long time and tests it finally worked!!
The code should be follwing:

`$result = $db_connect->query("SELECT $fields FROM members where id = $id");

     while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         return ($data);
  }`

By the way I'm sorry that your post got a downvote, I think someone is doing it on purpose. THANK YOU AGAIN!